# jQuery do not allow alphabets to be entered in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

My requirement is to not allow user to type in any Alphabets. The below code allows 1 character to be entered even though I have provided the `e.preventDefault()` method on both `keydown` and `keyup` methods.

```js
$(function() {
  // Regular Expression to Check for Alphabets.
  var regExp = new RegExp('[a-zA-Z]');

  $('#test').on('keydown keyup', function(e) {

    var value = $(this).val();

    // Do not allow alphabets to be entered.
    if (regExp.test(value)) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }

  }); // End of 'keydown keyup' method.

}); // End of 'document ready'
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="test" name="test" />
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there some other way to get this done?

Comment: Make sure to validate your field before using its value. You can still enter an alphabetic character in that field.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/672qc1q3/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny Replace `/a-z/i` by `/[a-z]/i` in your fiddle.

Comment: You have a very loose concept of _alphabetic characters_. If you're limited to **basic latin** characters then yes, it works. However if an Italian, French, German or anyone else will type "à" then your code won't stop him to do it. Instead it'll stop everyone who uses an IME where a single (non _alphabetic_) character is made by two Unicode code points...

Comment: @Xufox, I'm following your example..

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti, Yes I will have to change my Regular Expression to allow only numbers rather than NOT allow alphabets.

Comment: @GauthamPJ if you want only number then go for type numbers

Comment: @GauthamPJ don't forget that also _digit_ is a wide concept (2, ٢, ۲, 二, 兩 and 两 are all the same digit but in different alphabets; 2nd and 3rd are different even if look the same). If you need to support only Arabic numbers then yes, go with a simple regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
var value = $(this).val();
```

by

```
var value = String.fromCharCode(e.which) || e.key;
```

After all, you need to check which key has been pressed *before* allowing a character to be typed into the field.

Also, make sure the backspace and delete buttons and arrow keys aren’t blocked!

```js
$(function() {
  var regExp = /[a-z]/i;
  $('#test').on('keydown keyup', function(e) {
    var value = String.fromCharCode(e.which) || e.key;

    // No letters
    if (regExp.test(value)) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="test" name="test" />
```

If your goal is to only accept numbers, dots and commas use this function instead:

```js
$(function() {
  var regExp = /[0-9\.\,]/;
  $('#test').on('keydown keyup', function(e) {
    var value = String.fromCharCode(e.which) || e.key;
    console.log(e);
    // Only numbers, dots and commas
    if (!regExp.test(value)
      && e.which != 188 // ,
      && e.which != 190 // .
      && e.which != 8   // backspace
      && e.which != 46  // delete
      && (e.which < 37  // arrow keys
        || e.which > 40)) {
          e.preventDefault();
          return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="test" name="test" />
```

Comment: I actually need `numbers`, `comma` `,` and `dot` `.` character. But the `String.fromCharCode()` does not return `,` and `.` characters properly. Is there a way to validate these characters?

Comment: @GauthamPJ Do you need to block or accept numbers, dots and commas?

Comment: I need to Accept only Numbers, Dot and Comma.
I used an array of required character codes to check for validity. Got it working properly. Thanks again.

Comment: @GauthamPJ I’ve edited my answer. Now both cases should be covered.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store input data somewhere and update it each time user inputs allowed character or reset when disabled

```
$(function() {
// Regular Expression to Check for Alphabets.
var regExp = new RegExp('[a-zA-Z]'),
    inputVal = '';

$('#test').on('keydown keyup', function(e) {

    var value = $(this).val();

    // Do not allow alphabets to be entered.
    if (regExp.test(value)) {
        $(this).val(inputVal)
    }
    else{ 
        inputVal = value
    }

}); // End of 'keydown keyup' method.

}); // End of 'document ready'
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but @Xufox has provided a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function that will mask it out

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4yL2a2wk/)

```
$.fn.noMask = function(regex) { 
  this.on("keypress", function(e) {
    if (regex.test(String.fromCharCode(e.which))) {
        return false;
    }
  });
}

$("input").noMask ( /[a-zA-Z]/ );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying for only alphabet with space you can try it:

```
$("#test").on("keypress keyup blur",function (event) { 

 $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/, ""));

if (!((event.charCode > 64 && 
    event.charCode < 91) || event.charCode ==32 || (event.charCode > 96 && 
      event.charCode < 123))) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will allow only numbers to be accepted for example in a telepone number input field. This is the improvement on the accepted answer.

```
var regExp = /[0-9]/;
      $("#test").on('keydown keyup blur focus', function(e) {

        var value =e.key;
        /*var ascii=value.charCodeAt(0);
        $('textarea').append(ascii);
        $('textarea').append(value);
        console.log(e);*/
        // Only numbers
        if (!regExp.test(value)
          && e.which != 8   // backspace
          && e.which != 46  // delete
          && (e.which < 37  // arrow keys
            || e.which > 40)) {
              e.preventDefault();
              return false;
        }
      });
```